# HTML/CSS - Image inside a li element from the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar, and underneath a black div on which the drop-down elements from the navigation bar drops. This is not the main function of the black div. It is just for design, but it works really well. You can see here what i am talking about: http://www.ecoloc.ro/interior/test/regeneration . Now, what i want to do is that every time a main element from the navigation bar is hovered, an image big enough to cover the main element and a part of that black div beneath it will appear. You can see in the link that i posted, on that black gap i want the image. Can this be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the dimensions of the `<a>` inside the `<li>` and set a background image for it. If you don't want the main menu word to appear, you just set `text-indent: -9999px´ on ´:hover´ (image replacement technique).

The best way to set the modifications on hover and come back to normal on hout is to create different classes with the styles. So you change the class via JavaScript on hover, changing the dimensions automaticaly.

Comment: thank you very much! I will try this, and tell you my results!

Comment: I really think that this could work. the problem is that the extended part of the `<a>` is not on top the black `<div>`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can manage the `<a>` position and dimentions, setting `margin`, `width` and `height` differently on hover (as welll as setting the bg image).

Comment: I added `position:absolute;` on the class `.hover` and the `<a>` went on top. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use absolute positioning for your "submenu" list, you should be able to do it with a little CSS.

Provide a `background-image:` for the list element that contains your desired graphics, set `background-repeat: no-repeat`, set an absolute `height:` and re-position your list to the correct `top:`, `left:` corner. Use `margin:` and `padding:` to get the list elements into their correct position.

-- Update: --

Try the following quick and dirty first sketch to see if I got the idea:

```
<ul id="media" style="position: absolute; top: 108px; left: 1018px; height: 35px; background-color: red; padding-left: 131px; padding-top: 35px; ">
        <li><a href="#" title="" data-description="starts here">presa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="" data-description="starts here">video</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="" data-description="starts here">foto</a></li>
</ul>
```

The submenu covers your main menu entry and the black submenu bar. Provide an image that covers exactly the areas you want and fine tune the positioning.

Comment: But he wants the image only on hover.

Comment: No problem, use the `:hover` declaration on the list class, like li.myclass:hover.

Comment: On the other hand, the submenu list is actually not visible without hovering over the main menu item. So there is no need for `:hover` selector.

Comment: it is not working Joker. You can see yourself. If you have any other idea let me know. thanks.